# DOM Internet explorer set attiribute on querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript, powershell

I'm having trouble on setting attributes using Powershell IE.
I'm trying to set values of all elements of a select as "selected", but for some reason i'm not able to exec javascript code directly with execscript.
The following works on native Javascript

```
for (let i = 0 ; i < document.getElementById('iframe_app_menu').contentWindow.document.querySelector('[name="categoriaid_orig"]').querySelectorAll("option[value*=$categoria]").length ; i++){
document.getElementById('iframe_app_menu').contentWindow.document.querySelector('[name="categoriaid_orig"]').querySelectorAll("option[value*=$categoria]")[i].setAttribute("selected", "true")
}
```

I've tried to emulate it in powershell with:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < document.getElementById('iframe_app_menu').contentWindow.document.querySelector('[name="categoriaid_orig"]').querySelectorAll("option[value*=$categoria]").length ; $i++){
document.getElementById('iframe_app_menu').contentWindow.document.querySelector('[name="categoriaid_orig"]').querySelectorAll("option[value*=$categoria]")[$i].setAttribute("selected", "true")
}
```

But it return the error "0x80020101".

For some reason the "[]" character doesn't work in powershell and it doesn't support ECMAScript2015
I've tried with the following:

[How to use JavaScript's setattribute to affect multiple elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455353/how-to-use-javascripts-setattribute-to-affect-multiple-elements)

[Javascript for..in looping over arguments ie.for( arg in arguments) does not work in IE8 but it works in Chrome 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824207/javascript-for-in-looping-over-arguments-ie-for-arg-in-arguments-does-not-wor)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.